How to know if Flutter app is killed or in background when recieve a notification
I have a use-case to execute some action upon receiving a notification only in the killed state in Flutter app.
In background as well as killed(i.e. terminated) state of app the notification control comes in Future<void> firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) function. What I need is to determine whether the app is currently in background or killed. Upon that I need to perform some action.
Like:--
Future<void> firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
   await Firebase.initializeApp();
   if(isAppKilled()){
      doKilledAction(message);
   }
}

How do I implement isAppKilled() ?
